# save a reddit page for reference

Tags: reddit

I'd like to browse through the topics of Reddit but the page was loading ahead whenever I scrolled down. If I click into a thread and then wanted to go back to the previous position then most likely I have to take some time to scroll down to that position again to continue with what I have read before.

Is there any way to pause the page. Or alternatively to download the whole page for browsing offline?

Thank you for your suggestion